# How do i Count number of Values in a column and write it in a new column in R?

Tags: r, dataset

Suppose there  is a column with values

```
Website
Abc
Abc
Abc
Xyz
Xyz
Pqr
Uvw
```

Now i want to count how many times Abc or other names is in the column and write the count corresponding in the next column .

```
Website      Total
    Abc            3
    Abc            3
    Abc            3
    Xyz            2 
    Xyz            2
    Pqr            1
    Uvw            1
```

Can a function be created Without manually counting each website?

Comment: You can do this with `dplyr`: `DF %>% 
  group_by(Website) %>% 
  mutate(n=n())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) ave** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, we can use `ave` to apply `length` to each group:

```
transform(DF, Count = ave(seq_along(Website), Website, FUN = length))
```

giving:

```
  Website Count
1     Abc     3
2     Abc     3
3     Abc     3
4     Xyz     2
5     Xyz     2
6     Pqr     1
7     Uvw     1
```

**2) aggregate** or without duplicates:

```
aggregate(list(Count = 1:nrow(DF)), DF["Website"], length)
```

giving:

```
  Website Count
1     Abc     3
2     Pqr     1
3     Uvw     1
4     Xyz     2
```

**3) table** Another approach is to create a table rather than a data.frame:

```
table(DF)
```

giving:

```
DF
Abc Pqr Uvw Xyz 
  3   1   1   2
```

**4) xtabs** or we can use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(DF)
```

giving:

```
Website
Abc Pqr Uvw Xyz 
  3   1   1   2
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Website
Abc
Abc
Abc
Xyz
Xyz
Pqr
Uvw"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with `tidyverse` is `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  add_count(Website)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  Website     n
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 Abc         3
#2 Abc         3
#3 Abc         3
#4 Xyz         2
#5 Xyz         2
#6 Pqr         1
#7 Uvw         1
```